# After uploading image in Cloudinary through React-native unable to get url as response

Tags: react-native, cloudinary

> While uploading image to cloudinary from react-native unable to get Image URL as response.
> but image is successfully uploaded on the cloud.

My Response is
{"_parts": [["file", [Object]], ["upload_preset", "******"], ["cloud_name","******"]]}

Comment: The upload API returns a JSON object in the response with details of the uploaded file: https://cloudinary.com/documentation/image_upload_api_reference#sample_response
To persist the image details, you should take that response and send it to your backend so you can use the information to update your database or other state

Comment: but i am getting this as a response.    {"_parts": [["file", [Object]], ["upload_preset", "*****"], ["cloud_name", "******"]]}

Comment: That doesn't look like the response from the API, if the cloud_name and upload_preset values are present, that looks like the configuration you passed to the SDK, or the parameters you were going to send on the API call itself